# Combining three arrays by Index position

Tags: php, arrays

After several attempts I couldn't figure out a efficient way to do this. I currently have a function running `preg_match_all` and returning three arrays like this;

```
array(3) {
    ["name"] => 
        array(3) { 
             0 => "Google Chrome 22.0.1229.94",
             1 => "LastPass for Chrome 2.0.7",
             2 => "Chromatic 0.2.3"
        }

    ["link"] => 
        array(3) {
            0 => "/app/mac/32956/google-chrome",
            1 => "/app/mac/42578/lastpass-for-chrome",
            2 => "/app/mac/32856/chromatic"
        }

    ["description"] =>
        array(3) {
            0 => " - Modern and fast Web browser."
            1 => " - Online password manager and form filler for Chrome."
            2 => " - Easily install and updated Chromium."
    }
}
```

I need to able to combine the three arrays like this;

```
array(3) {
    array(3) {
        ["name"]        = "Google Chrome 22.0.1229.94",
        ["link"]        = "/app/mac/32956/google-chrome",
        ["description"] = " - Modern and fast Web browser."
    }

    array(3) {
        ["name"]        = "LastPass for Chrome 2.0.7",
        ["link"]        = "/app/mac/42578/lastpass-for-chrome",
        ["description"] = " - Online password manager and form filler for Chrome."
    }

    array(3) {
        ["name"]        = "Chromatic 0.2.3",
        ["link"]        = "/app/mac/32856/chromatic",
        ["description"] = " - Easily install and updated Chromium."
    }
}
```

I've been trying to `count( $values )` and doing a for loop to make new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my take, for your particular case, given your origin array is `$results` :

```
for ($i=0; $i<3;$i++) {
   $combined[$i]['name'] = $results['name'][$i];
   $combined[$i]['link'] = $results['link'][$i];
   $combined[$i]['description'] = $results['description'][$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll go ahead and suggest that what you're *really* looking for is the `PREG_SET_ORDER` flag for `preg_match_all`:

```
preg_match_all('/.../', $foo, $bar, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

http://php.net/preg_match_all

Otherwise:

```
$results = array();
foreach ($matches as $key => $values) {
    foreach ($values as $index => $value) {
        $results[$index][$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: `PREG_SET_ORDER` isn't going to work because of the way I'm parsing it, it finds all the matches for `"name"`, then `"link"`, then `"description"`. I'm trying to make it work with the *otherwise* in your answer.